# AWS RDS MSSQL unusably slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I figured when I started a project on AWS RDS and using MSSQL that it would be fast or at least usable. It's neither - I have an MSSQL server running in a VPC, but using MSSQL Management studio is almost impossible because it's so slow (talking minutes to get a response on a right click function in Management Studio). I have fast internet and no connectivity issues. Has anyone else come across this issue - is there a tweek in Management Studio that I don't know about?

I think I should have used Azure...

Comment: That would totally depend on what you are running on rds and what is the instance size , if you expect to run heavy workloads on free tier i think it would not be possible.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much confirmed what I assumed.

Comment: What is the Size of the database, the DB instance class, the DB Engine Version and Storage type, all of these attributes effect on the performance of the SQL server. Also it may help to read thru this https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/RDS/Deploying_SQLServer_on_AWS.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the accepted answer on this question:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104378/sql-server-management-studio-slow-connection-or-timeout-when-using-windows-authe

in particular, adding an entry into your hosts file.

I often have very slow connections using SSMS to any remote SQL server database, not just RDS.

Comment: I use SSMS connections to several remote servers, a couple behind firewalls and I've never seen anything like this before.